# Apache kafka - manual acknowledge(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL) not working and events replayed on library upgrade

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Kafka events getting replayed to consumer repeatedly. I can see following exception -

```
5-Nov-2019 10:43:25 ERROR [org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run : 685] :: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1 ::  :: Container exception
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: 
Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 
This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. 
You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

But in my case, it's just 1 message which takes more than 30 mins to process so we acknowledge it on receiving. So i don't think no.of records is an issue. I know it can be solved by increasing max.poll.interval.ms but it used to work before upgrade. Trying to figure out what is optimal workaround.

Tried with ***AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE*** seems to commit offset immediately and works, but I need to figure out why ***AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL*** fails now

Previous working jar versions:
***spring-kafka-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar
kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar***

Current versions (getting above exception):
***spring-kafka-1.3.9.RELEASE.jar
kafka-clients-2.2.1.jar***

Comment: did u check what was the value of `max.poll.interval.ms` inthe old version? at one stage kafka defaulted it to Integer.max

Comment: in previous version used there is no property max.poll.interval.ms. in new one its 5 mins. but we are acknowleding on message receive so not sure this property causing it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must increase `max.poll.interval.ms`; you can use MANUAL_IMMEDIATE instead to commit the offset immediately (with MANUAL, the commit is enqueued, the actual commit is not performed until the thread exits the listener).

However, this will still not prevent a rebalance because Kafka requires the consumer to call `poll()` within `max.poll.interval.ms`.

So I suggest you switch to MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and increase the interval beyond 30 minutes.

With the old version (before 1.3), there were two threads - one for the consumer and one for the listener, so the queued ack was processed earlier. But it was a very complicated threading model which was much simplified in 1.3, thanks to KIP-62, but this side effect was the result.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But what I observed was - just switched to MANUAL_IMMEDIATE without changing max.poll.interval.ms and message processing took around 20 mins after manual immediate was acknowledged and we didn't observe any rebalance or message sent again to consumer

Comment: I tried to explain, while the offset will be committed properly, you will still experience an unnecessary rebalance on the next poll. Please read KIP-62 -